# equal sign appear low back color and in above line of equation

Tags: color

```
=$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda\rho\sin(x_i-X_i)-\dfrac{1}{c}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{-\beta_i\eta_1\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)+\beta_i\eta_2\cos(y_i-\beta_iX_i)}{1-\alpha_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\alpha_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}$$
```

2) estimate of `$\rho$` need to write it with dark black

Comment: Yet a gain, please post a full minimal example such that others can test it and not having to guess 2/3 of a document.

Comment: you are just making it hard for people to see the issue or help you if you post code that no one can run

Comment: but why have you got the `=` _before_ the equation?

Comment: what yo mean with "estimate of $\rho$ need to write it with dark black"? should the symbol `$\rho$` be in boldface? all math expression has black color ...

Comment: see if https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics can help you at writing of math.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use `$$..$$` for displayed math, use `\[..\]`. Second, `=` should be inside math-mode as my first example below. If the equation is wider than the `\textwidth`, consider using `align` for splitting the equation over two lines as my second example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda\rho\sin(x_i-X_i)-\dfrac{1}{c}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{-\beta_i\eta_1\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)+\beta_i\eta_2\cos(y_i-\beta_iX_i)}{1-\alpha_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\alpha_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}
\]

\begin{align*}
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda\rho\sin(x_i-X_i) \\
&\phantom{{}=}-\dfrac{1}{c}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{-\beta_i\eta_1\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)+\beta_i\eta_2\cos(y_i-\beta_iX_i)}{1-\alpha_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\alpha_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]